# trouble authorize asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Plz, help in my trouble.

I created new application in MS VS 2017. Type ASP.NET Core 2 MVC

I can't find solution for my problem with authorize.

1. I added to Startup

   ```
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
       services.AddScoped<USDb, USDb>();
       services.Scan(scan => scan.FromAssemblyOf<USDb>()
           .AddClasses()
           .AsImplementedInterfaces());
       InjectionContainer = services.BuildServiceProvider();
       services.AddMvc();
       //Auth
       services.AddAuthentication(o => {
           o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           o.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       })
           .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o => {
               o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
               o.ReturnUrlParameter = "RedirectUrl";
               o.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/AccessDenied");
               o.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout");
               o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
               o.SlidingExpiration = true;

               o.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
               o.Cookie.Name = ".USAUTH";
           });
   }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
       if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
           app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
           app.UseBrowserLink();
       } else {
           app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
       }

       app.UseStaticFiles();

       app.UseMvc(routes => {
           routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
       });
       app.UseAuthentication();

   }
   ```
2. My AccountController method

   ```
       [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model, string redirectUrl = null) {
       if (ModelState.IsValid) {
           await Authenticate("login"); 

           return Redirect(redirectUrl);

       }

       return View();
   }

   private async Task Authenticate(string userName) {
   ```

   var claims = new List{ new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, userName) };
             
               ClaimsIdentity id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

   ```
       await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(id));
   }
   ```

When I try to go Home/Index application redirect me to account - it's very good. But after I entered login data and submited it to login method application redirect me to login page again... and again.... etc
But cookies appeared, but application not created HttpContext.User.Identity and still redirecting me to login page.... 
And I don't know what todo(((( please help(( I lose the hope(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseMvc(...);`.

Banal error but I had the same problem a while ago after upgrading to asp.net core 2.0.